# Django Order By Query on Methods in Models

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have this model:

```
class User(models.Model):
  uid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, unique=True)
  password = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
  contact = models.CharField(max_length=10)
  cash_amount = models.IntegerField(default=25000)
  share_amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  def __str__(self):
    return self.email
  def total_amount(self):
    return self.cash_amount + self.share_amount
```

How to write QuerySet for ordering the result on the basis of **total_amount()**, I tried below query:

```
User.objects.order_by('total_amount()')
```

But FieldError: Invalid order_by arguments: ['total_amount()'] comes.

Is there any other way possible of writing the query for ordering the result on the basis of **cash_amount + share_amount** without creating the **total_amount()**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [`extra`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#extra)

```
User.objects.extra(
    select={'field_sum' : 'cash_amount + share_amount'},
    order_by=('field_sum',)
)
```

Comment: Use of extra is now discouraged and being depreciated. Use RawSQL instead.